# AngularJs - route resolve function does not recognize factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm using AngularJS 1.6.1, and I'm trying to do a simple task that I have already done before (long time ago), but for some reason I can't realize what is happening this time.

Basically I want to call my REST service, but when I pass my `factory` in the parameters of the `resolve` function, it stops working.

I made a simple example to post here in order to make it easier:

index.html

```
<html ng-app="TesteApp">
<head>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>

  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ng-view">
    </div>
</body>
```

view.html

```
<h1>DONE</h1>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('TesteApp', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('TesteApp').controller('testeController', function($scope, resultSet) {
   console.log("1");
});

angular.module('TesteApp').config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        templateUrl: "view.html",
        controller: "testeController",
        resolve: {
            resultSet: function(callApi) { // seems like 'callApi' is not being recognized?!
                //If I return the fixed list below and take the 'callApi' parameter above, it works.
                //return "[{id:1, nome: 'teste'}, {id:2, nome: 'teste2'}]";
                return callApi.getResult(); 
            }
        }
    });
});

angular.module("TesteApp").factory("callApi", function ($http, config) {
    var _getResult = function () {
        return $http.get("http://localhost:8080/result");
    };

    return {
        getResult: _getResult
    };
});
```

Like I said in the comment, it seems like 'callApi' is not recognized.

The console does not print errors and the `<div class="ng-view">`is not replaced by `<h1>DONE</h1>`, and no request is in fact done.

Comment: What exactly is 'not recognized'? If you've got an error, pease, post it entirely.

Comment: @estus Do you have any idea, why `confi` dependency injection inside `callApi` factory fails silently in [above code](https://plnkr.co/edit/DOxIxNuZ9Z3MJmRpQ2cF?p=preview). It doesn't throw an error in console. I never saw this before :( Sorry for asking you here

Comment: @PankajParkar Hi. No problems. That's because the service is first injected in resolver and injection error in factory results in resolver rejection and router error, https://plnkr.co/edit/IS73Ux4yjaKVuMCR8U9q?p=preview . I don't think I encountered this before, but yes, it makes perfect sense, that's how I would expect it to work. I guess it makes sense to set up $routeChangeError handler in dev environment, thanks for drawing my attention to this, good to keep it in mind.

Comment: @estus great! great! great!, You always add good informative comments every time. I learnt something new today :) You're awesome as always. Thanks much :)

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to see you among Angular fellows on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

Its wiered(as it isn't throwing any error in console), but `config` dependency injected inside `callApi` wasn't mentioned anywhere, so it is failing there. Removed that `unknown` dependency will fix your issue.

[**Demo Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/DOxIxNuZ9Z3MJmRpQ2cF?p=preview)

---

You had wrong service method name. Instead of `getArticles` call `getResult`.

```
return callApi.getArticles();
```

should be

```
return callApi.getResult();
```

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake when I replaced a few things to post here. The problem still happens.

Comment: Can you please update code & exact error that you're getting

Comment: @BrunoBL check updated answer :) Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Right, for this example it solves. My original app actually has the 'config', and the problem still occurs.. even taking config. but for this simple example I did, it is working, so I will consider your answer and try figure out things in original app. Thank you :)